# Pandas - remove every NaN from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with `NaN`s scattered throughout it and would like to remove them all so I'm just left with my data.

Here is a printout of my dataframe `fish_frame`:

```
fish_frame:                         0       1       2         3  \
0                   735-8     NaN     NaN       NaN   
1                     NaN     NaN     NaN  LIVE WGT   
2                 GBE COD     NaN     NaN       600   
3                 GBW COD     NaN  11,189       NaN   
4                 GOM COD     NaN       0       NaN   
5                 POLLOCK     NaN     NaN     1,103   
6                   WHAKE     NaN     NaN        12   
7             GBE HADDOCK     NaN  10,730       NaN   
8             GBW HADDOCK     NaN  64,147       NaN   
9             GOM HADDOCK     NaN       0       NaN   
10                REDFISH     NaN     NaN         0   
11         WITCH FLOUNDER     NaN     370       NaN   
12                 PLAICE     NaN     NaN       622   
13     GB WINTER FLOUNDER  54,315     NaN       NaN   
14    GOM WINTER FLOUNDER     653     NaN       NaN   
15  SNEMA WINTER FLOUNDER  14,601     NaN       NaN   
16          GB YELLOWTAIL     NaN   1,663       NaN   
17       SNEMA YELLOWTAIL     NaN   1,370       NaN   
18       CCGOM YELLOWTAIL   1,812     NaN       NaN   

                            4      6        package_deal_column Package_Price  
0                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69           nan  
1                         NaN  TOTAL  Package Deal - $40,753.69           nan  
2                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
3                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
4   Package Deal - $40,753.69   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
5                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
6                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
7                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
8                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
9                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
10                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
11                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
12                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
13                        NaN   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
14                        NaN   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
15                        NaN   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
16                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
17                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
18                        NaN   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None
```

Ideally, for columns 2, 3, and 4 I would like there to be no `NaN`s and for the numbers to all be in one column instead of three.

I used the command `fish_frame = fish_frame.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` but it didn't alter the dataframe at all.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: can you upload the file?

Comment: As in what was the original source I got this data from?

Comment: yes or just upload the csv/excel file

Comment: It's an HTML table embedded in the body of an email. Should I just upload the entire HTML code?

Comment: no it is okay. i will post an example using other (my) data

Comment: i think you have a bit longer process needed. one column instead of 3? you might want to use `fillna` instead, fill them with 0s, create a new column that is the 3 columns added together. `how="all"` won't do anything here, because it only drops columns that are _all_ nan, and all your columns have at least one non-NaN value (not sure about the Package_Price column, but since it has both None and nan, pandas may be confused).

Comment: @CorleyBrigman you might be right about it requiring a more in depth solution. I've posted several questions trying to be specific in my attempts to solve this. And the fact that I'm not a pandas expert doesn't help.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I tried that and got `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'transform'` ?

Comment: @theprowler i posted a possible answer

Comment: What do you want to replace the `NaN`s with? Because those cells aren't going away; you can't just remove the `NaN`s without putting something else in their place. Remember that the `DataFrame` will always be a rectangle - in many cases, its size stays the same, and those operations that do change its size will only do so by adding/removing entire rows or entire columns.

Comment: @theprowler That means you're working on an older version of pandas. Try upgrading and do it again? `df.loc[:, 2:5].transform(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)`

Comment: @DavidZ right, I guess this wasn't a great specific enough question. I'd like to just combine those columns so the numbers in one column would replace the `NaN`s in another column. But i've been failing at trying to do that for some time now

Comment: @theprowler I edited my answer. it works fine for the data that you uploaded

Comment: @theprowler If I understand correctly, you're talking about merging columns 2-4 into a new column so that for each row, if exactly one of those three columns contains a number, then that number appears in the new column? In that case, what should be done where none of columns 2-4 contains a number? Or what if there is more than one number in the same row among columns 2-4?

Comment: @DavidZ well if none contain a number I can live with one `NaN` being in a column. And I don't think there should be a case where one row has more than one number in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('fish.csv',header = None)

df_new = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

df_new = df_new.fillna(value=0)
```

This will replace all the NaN and strings with 0.

Then you can add the 3 columns and get 1 columns with all the numbers as you said.

```
df_total = df_new[1] + df_new[2] + df_new[3]
```

This approach would only work in your case since you do not have values at the same lines of the same columns.

Comment: Is that a simple enough task? I assume I'd use commands such as `concatenate` and etc ?

Comment: Yes. this could work. then you can use: df_total = df_new[1] + df_new[2] + df_new[3] to add and get only one column. However, this will work only if there are no 2 values in the same line for the same columns (in the example that you posted it works)

Comment: Hmm that came back with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` on the addition of dataframe indices line..

Comment: @sorry i missed the string that you have in your data. I edited my answer. now it should work

Comment: Um. Will `pd.read_csv` work on an email that contains and HTML table?

Comment: this command is used to load a csv file. So you need to have a csv with the data. Where do you store your data? is it difficult to store the data in a csv file ?

Comment: So I store the `.eml` file in a folder, and I access the table in that file with: `with open(file_path) as in_f:
    msg = email.message_from_file(in_f) 

html_msg = msg.get_payload(1)  

body = html_msg.get_payload(decode=True)    

html = body.decode()`

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can transform the html variable into a pandas dataframe and then use the solution I posted. For the transformation see also [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

Answer (score 1):

Doing the add could be something like

```
 df['TotalVal'] = df[[0,1,2]].fillna(0).T.sum()
```

or

```
 df['TotalVal'] = df[[0,1,2]].fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Though... based on your questions, and the particular ways the data is 'weird', I might actually suggest you do the cleaning *before* this goes into pandas - it would be a lot easier to do I think, using the `csv` module to create a set of tuples, and build the dataframe from there.

I'm not an expert, and it took me a while to wrap my head around the pandas paradigms, but you have to think functionally (think results, not process) and consider shapes of data.

In this case, we want a single series with the same index as the original dataframe. So first, extract columns of interest. Since we don't have a named index, to ensure alignment, we don't want to drop or add any data. I use `fillna` just to replace the NaNs with a valid value that will be a no-op for my chosen algorithm.

This gives me a modified dataframe with 3 columns and my original index. Most pandas functions act on *columns*, but what we want is a sum of each *row*. So T transposes the dataframe so that instead of each *row* being a fish with 3 data samples, each *column* is a fish with 3 data rows. (you can also just tell it to sum over axis=1, which the description is backwards from what I understand it, but axis=1 means 'sum over columns' = per row)

Then we sum them, which will sum each column and, since that's just a single data point, also collapse them back into a single series. Which is what we want, and we can just drop it in the dataframe at that point.

Answer (score -1):

```
fish_frame.dropna(axis=1, how='any')
```

will remove any columns that have at least one NaN.

Comment: But will that remove the entire column, including all the valuable data?

Comment: @theprowler of course. you don't want NaN. Something needs to be there, either a NaN or a number. If you want to keep your data don't remove NaN but replace it with 0s or something else with filna()